# SPF MX mechanism number of lookups

Tags: email, dns, spf

I'm currently working on some code for validating SPF records. However when comparing my results for number of lookups with other tools such as MxToolbox and EasyDMARC they seem off.

Currently I'm doing something like the following code.

```cs
if (directive.Mechanism == SpfMechanism.MX)
{
    _lookups++;
    
    // Lookup the MX records
    var records = _resolver.GetMXRecords(directive.MX);
    
    foreach (var record in records)
    {
        // Do an A lookup for the MX record
        _lookups++;
        
        // ...
    }
}
```

However I'm unsure about incrementing the number of lookups for every MX record.

The RFC mentions

> check_host() first performs an MX lookup on the .  Then
> it performs an address lookup on each MX name returned.  The  is
> compared to each returned IP address.  To prevent denial-of-service
> (DoS) attacks, the processing limits defined in Section 4.6.4 MUST be
> followed.  If the MX lookup limit is exceeded, then "permerror" is
> returned and the evaluation is terminated.  If any address matches,
> the mechanism matches.

But it's not very clear about whether these should be counted, public implementations also seem to differ on this.

Comment: You don’t say whether your results are are higher or lower than what you are expecting.

Comment: The results I'm getting are higher than expected, exceeding the max lookup limit.

Comment: We don't really have anything to go on here. Without seeing what results you're getting for a given domain, we're working blind.

Comment: I'm mostly wondering how I should count those MX lookups. A very rough example is `v=spf1 mx:gmail.com -all` my code will be counting 6 lookups (one for the MX, 5 for the 
A lookup for each MX record), while other tools only count one lookup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading the RFC again very carefully the lookup limit is actually the limit of mechanisms that does a lookup. And each MX mechanism has a lookup of 10, independent from the lookup limit.

My problem was solved by making these changes, and now my results are identical to other SPF tools and libraries.

Comment: Interesting conclusion, but it seems a bit strange as it really opens the door to more or less unlimited lookups, rather defeating the point of having a limit.

Comment: Surprised as well, seems a well crafted SPF record can actually cause up to 100 lookups.